# What should be the return type of clone()?

Tags: java, overriding, clone

For example, I have class Human and i want to Override the clone() function.

What should be the return type of clone(), Object or Human? I know that return type doesn't have any role in the overriding process  because it is not in the function's signature.

For example, in class Human should i have

```
 public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException { 

    Human h = (Human)super.clone();

    h.age = age;
    h.name = name;


    return h;
}
```

and then in the main

```
 public static void main() throws CloneNotSupportedException { 



    Human h = new Human("Slavco", 49);

    Human z = (Human)h.clone();
}
```

**OR**

```
public Human clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException { 

    Human h = (Human)super.clone();

    h.age = age;
    h.name = name;


    return h;
}
```

and in the main

```
public static void main() throws CloneNotSupportedException { 



    Human h = new Human("Slavco", 49);

    Human z = h.clone();
}
```

Comment: What is the reason *not* to return `Human`? and yes, the return type *does* have a rule in overriding: it hould be a subtype of the original return type.

Comment: They both override the default Object constructor, but returning the Human in the method definition is clearer, it also allows you to call clone on a human object and not have to cast.

Comment: Tip: Instead of calling `super.clone()`, you could simply do this: `return new Human(name, age);`.

Answer (score 4):

Returning a `Human` will make your life much easier (probably save you a lot of casting), and there is no downside to it.
I would definitely recommend that approach.

Comment: @DonRoby It compiles since `Human` is a subclass of `Object`. The return type doesn't have to be the same.